# Getting Build Error: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class`

Tags: android

I am getting the error of duplicate entry:Java/annotation/check for null. I have tried to solve this issue yet not solved. I have fixed all the issue which getting and found google each and everything related to  but not solved.
Help me what to do

```
   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
     compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

           packagingOptions {
            exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
            exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
            exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
            exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
            pickFirst 'javax/annotation/**' // add this
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }


}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.2.0'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
  //  compile files('libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }


}
```

Comment: Giving such info won't  work. Paste your build.gradle file so that every one can understand your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may solve duplicate error using this in build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'javax/annotation/**' // add this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for given a quick update,  I have added above code but not working getting same error